# Why does this work?? Class Meta, model = User

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Can someone please explain this?? I'm in the process of trying my first post-tutorial project.

I've made a model called Profile with 4 attributes (given_name, surname, bio, image). I've made a form called ProfileForm which inherits from UserCreationForm and i've added the 4 attributes of my model into the form as form attributes.

MY Question is:

Why does it only work like this

```
class Meta:
   model = User
```

This is my models.py file

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    given_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.given_name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['given_name']
```

This is my forms.py file

```
class ProfileForm(UserCreationForm):
    firstName = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    lastName = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    bio = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    image = forms.ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'username', 'password1', 'password2', 'bio', 'image']
```

This is my views.py file

```
def sign_up_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST": 

        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES) 

        if form.is_valid(): 
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)

            profile = Profile.objects.create(
                given_name=form.cleaned_data['firstName'], 
                surname = form.cleaned_data['lastName'],
                bio = form.cleaned_data['bio'],
                image = form.cleaned_data['image'])

            

            return redirect('home')

    else:
        form = ProfileForm()   

    return render(request, 'core/sign_up.html', {"form": form})
```

This is my admin page for a profile.
[image: Admin Page Created Profile]

This is my admin page for a User

[image]

Note : I'm able to achieve my desired outcome, but I'm having trouble in understanding how its working.
**Also if i wanted to link the Profile model with the User such that, if the User is deleted in admin then the respective profile would also get deleted??

Comment: Because `username`, etc. are not fields of your `Profile` model.

Comment: You should work with *two* forms, one that creates the `User` object, and one that creates the `Profile` object.

Comment: If i used two forms as you suggested, would i still be able to use a single sign-up page(form.as_p) in my html for creating a user and a profile?

Comment: Another problem is that your `Profile` model does not seem to have any link to the `User` model, as a result it is unclear which `Profile` belongs to which `User`.

Comment: Yes, that is something that i am trying to do (linking Profile model to the User model), but I'm unsure of how it is done and seem to run into errors constantly. I've tried OnetoOneField as well as ForeignKey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only works with `model = User`, because your fields, like `username`, etc. are fields of the `User` model, not of the `Profile` model.

What you can do is process the view with two forms. We thus make a form for the `Profile` model, and use the `UserCreationForm` for the `User`.

Furthermore the `Profile` needs to link to the user model, such that it is clear what `Profile` belongs to what user. We thus add a `ForeignKey` with:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Profile(models.Model):
    # ⋮
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        editable=False
    )

    # ⋮
```

then we can define a `Profile` form with:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

then we can work with two forms, the view looks like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

def sign_up_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserCreationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='profile')

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid(): 
            user = form.save()
            profile_form.instance.user = user
            profile_form.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')

    else:
        user_form = UserCreationForm()
        profile_form = ProfileForm(prefix='profile')
    context = {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form}
    return render(request, 'core/sign_up.html', context)
```

and in the template render it with:

```
<form action="{% url 'name-of-the-signup-view' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ user_form }}
    {{ profile_form }}
</form>
```

we thus use two Django forms in the same HTML form, and prefix the `ProfileForm` with `profile` for the input fields.